# Is the iplimage imagesize same as mat size?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Is the iplimage imagesize same as mat size? what is the difference and how can we replace them with each other?

Comment: AFAIK, you really should not be using `IplImage` any more.

Comment: Actually, i was updating code to opencv 4. So, i replaced iplImage with Mat, however in the code it was setting 

 `IplImage *p; p->ImageSize= (something), as i replaced it as
cv::Mat px; 
I wanted to know if p->imagesize is same as px.size.p(pointer to the size)?

Answer (score 0):

IplImage* is a pointer to the image data structure IplImage. It is used in C API of opencv.

After opencv 2.0, C++ API is introduced, and "Mat" structure replaced IplImage.

Well their data storage is the same,so the size is approximately the same ( if not exactly)

1- to go from cv::Mat to iplImage*

```
Mat frame;
// read the image...ect
IplImage* frame2 = cvCloneImage(&(IplImage)frame);
```

2- to go from iplImage to cv::Mat

```
IplImage * ipl = ...;
cv::Mat m = cv::cvarrToMat(ipl);
```